# Drawing a separator between columns in GridView Layout

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I have a GridView Layout with a 3x2 grid, the background of the app is a gradient and I need to add `white 1dp` separators between the columns, how can I do it? my xml is this:

```
  <GridLayout
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/white"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forecastDay1" />
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/white"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forecastDay2" />
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/white"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forecastDay3" />
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/white"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forecastTempDay1" />
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/white"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forecastTempDay2" />
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/white"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forecastTempDay3" />

</GridLayout>
```

I just need a thick white line that separates the columns without affecting the gradient background of the app

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding vertical views or horizontal views. Below are the code for the same respectively.

Vertical Line -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:background="#a40404" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Horizontal Line -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:background="#a40404" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Place the Views where ever it is necessary.